# Having two types of authentication methods

Tags: ssh, login, putty

So.. I can login to my ubuntu machine using private-public key method.

But now I need to have a user with regular username - password login method.

If I try to simply login with username (without specifying RSA key) in putty, I get Disconnected: no supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey) error.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, change the line

```
#PasswordAuthentication yes
```

to

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

and resart sshd:

```
service sshd restart
```

Answer (score 1):

You also may just run the given command into the terminal.

```
sed -i "s/PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

> N.B. Here "*PasswordAuthentication no*" replace with "*PasswordAuthentication yes*"
>
> So before run the command you may check using "***sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config***" what has the value PasswordAuthentication.
>
> Sometime it is written as "*#PasswordAuthentication yes*"
>
> Then command will be ***sed -i "s/#PasswordAuthentication yes/PasswordAuthentication yes/" /etc/ssh/sshd_config***

And for after Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
```

Or for before Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Won't work if the line doesn't exist or is prefixed (commented) with `#`.

Comment: then run sed -i "s/#PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/" /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: ...or `"s/#?PasswordAuthentication.*/PasswordAuthentication yes/"`

Comment: That's cool command.

Comment: @PerlDuck I found that `?` should be escaped as `\?`.
Maybe this one is better:
```sh
sudo sed -i 's/^#*\(PasswordAuthentication\).*$/\1 yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: @Mimyo Yes, there are so many ways. Both your and my suggestion won't work for `# Password…`, i.e. if there's a blank or tab between the `#` and the `Password`. As long as I don't need to update dozens of config files, I wouldn't put too much effort into a _bullet proof_ regex.